# checkbox update

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to update some text to say whether or not the checkbox is checked.  the only problem is that when it is checked, the textbox disappears, and the text replaces it.

```
<form name="form" id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb" onClick="check();" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        document.write("checked: " + document.form.cb.checked);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This happens because you use `document.write()` after the page is completed. You need to use some DOM manipulation instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is a side effect of using document.write. It is replacing the whole body of the document with the text you are writing. Try doing something like this instead.

```
<form name="form" id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb" onClick="check();" />
</form>

<div id="cb-status">checked: false</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        document.getElementById('cb-status').innerHTML = "checked: " + document.form.cb.checked;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i thought of this as a possibility, but thought there had to be another way.

Comment: i would just add <div id="cb-status">checked: false</div>

Comment: If you update you question to show the html for where you would like the message to be displayed then I can update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to make things easier for you:

Considering you have a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" >
```

And a span element with an id=message:

```
<span id="message"></span>
```

Then, when you click on a checkbox, it will "write" in the span if it is checked or not.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(":checkbox").click(function(){
       $("span#message").html("Checkbox is checked: " + $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

See it in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WNDUH/3/

Answer (score 0):

Bracket missing after html closing bracket for is(":checked") and string concat:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
     $("span#message").html("Checkbox is checked: " + $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```